# "ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed." when compiling aseprite

Tags: c++, error-handling, compiler-errors, compilation

I know there are many tutorials on how to compile aseprite and regarding this, but I just can't get it to work.

I have been following this tutorial: ninja: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4Enx-Nb43E , but also other ones (the same problem persists)

When doing `aseprite ninja` I eventually get this error and it stops: `ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.`

Can anyone send help or someone who had this problem and solved it?

(I am on windows 11)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using the wrong skia version, did you use [pre-built packages](https://github.com/aseprite/skia/releases)?

Comment: this could have been a comment.